# Use of まま in Japanese

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage, nuances, anime

I was watching an anime and the character said something along the lines of "私{わたし}は、このままでいいの". This translated into something like "Do I really want things to stay like this?" But what does まま do in this sentence? Does it mean to keep something in the state as it already is?

I feel like this is kind of a weird word since there's no direct Japanese-English translation.

Would this also work in past tense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

まま literally means "condition" or "state", or if you want to go fancy, "state of affairs."

Thus,

このまま = things being how they are
このままで =  keeping things how they are/things staying the way they are
私はこのままでいいの？ = Is it okay for me, if things stay the way they are? (the translation you saw essentially says the same thing)

So your understanding is pretty good.

I am not sure what exactly your last question is about. Do you mean to ask if まま can be used to talk about past events? Yes.

> そのままでよかったのに
> would have been nice if (things/I/you/someone/something) had stayed like that

Comment: Cheers! This was very helpful and made sense